# How to import Facebook Birthdays to get merge with Android Contacts?

Tags: contacts, sync, facebook

Apparently importing Facebook contacts to Android contacts is straight forward procedure by just checking sync option in Accounts and Settings, but is it possible to have birthday info imported from Facebook and merged with Android contacts.

PS: I was able to import FB birthdays imported to Google Calendar but that didn't help as the birthdays will just remain in calendar and not in Contacts.

Comment: I can never remember my mom's birthday either.

Answer (score 2):

If you sync your contacts with Google than you can add a special calendar. That you can only do on the web interface.

- Select Settings | Calendar settings in Google Calendar.
- Go to the Calendars tab.
- Follow the Browse interesting calendars » link under Other Calendars.
- Open the More tab.
- Click Subscribe for Contacts' birthdays and events.

Now after syncing the events will show up in the calendar app.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the android version.

I used to have Froyo and gingerbread (stock) it would not import the birthday info, but custom ROM MIUI does import the birthday info.